# using spring data jpa can not get id in transaction

Tags: transactions, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa to do entity persistance. I met a problem when i save data to database within transaction.

I test my repository, save method will fill id to the entity when there is no transaction, but when i use a transaction on the service, the save method doesn't fill id any more, i want to know why, any advise is appreciated

my service:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Long save(ClusterDTO clusterDTO) {
    Cluster cluster = clusterMapper.dtoToDO(clusterDTO);
    cluster.setGmtCreate(new Date());
    cluster.setGmtModified(new Date());
    clusterRepository.save(cluster);
    return cluster.getId();
}
```

my repository is very simple:

```java
public interface ClusterRepository extends CrudRepository<Cluster, Long> {
}
```

and my entity is :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "cluster")
public class Cluster {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long   id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    ...getters setters

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the updated cluster object returned by save method, so your code should look like:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Long save(ClusterDTO clusterDTO) {
    Cluster cluster = clusterMapper.dtoToDO(clusterDTO);
    cluster.setGmtCreate(new Date());
    cluster.setGmtModified(new Date());

    cluster = clusterRepository.save(cluster);

    return cluster.getId();
}
```

Comment: it seems unlikely this would work. JPA updates the ID on the persistent entity.